# updated Moment.js GAS library?

Tags: google-apps-script, momentjs

Does anyone know of an update Moment.js library for GAS ?
Eric Koleda made one , but it was a long time ago and doesn't include many important updates, like for example isBetween.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fortunately moment.js doesn't have any dependencies once built so you can fairly simply copy the moment.js code into any of your scripts whole sale.

Add a new script file to your Apps Script (call it moment.gs, say) and direct copy the raw code from [moment/moment.js @ github](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/moment/moment/develop/moment.js) and then reference it in the usual way:

```
var m = new moment();
```

This way you can have whatever version you wish, or even do this once and use your own as a library.

Comment: wow I didn't think to try that , thanks . I automatically assumed that since they made a GAS library for it it cannot be just added like this.

Comment: Should open up new DRY worlds to you with other code libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding to @JSDBroughton 's answer, there's also the [moment timezone package](https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone).

So, in order be able to get a `Date` translated to a given timezone, you can also add the moment-timezone, and then stuff like that is possible:

```
var testCases = [
  {tz: 'America/New_York'},
  {tz: 'America/Santiago'},
  {tz: 'America/Mexico_City'},
  {tz: 'America/Sao_Paulo'},
];

var m = new moment(new Date());
Logger.log('current moment=%s', m.format());
testCases.forEach(function(tc) {
  Logger.log('%s: %s', tc.tz, m.clone().tz(tc.tz).format());
});
```

And that will be really up-to-date, including daylight saving times and such.

For that, when creating the script file `moment.gs`, one must also include the `moment-timezone.js`, like that:

**Script file [moment.gs]**

```
[contents_from_moment_js]

[contents_from_moment-timezone_js]

moment.tz.load([contents_from_zones_json]);
```

[contents_from_moment_js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/moment/moment/develop/moment.js)

[contents_from_moment-timezone_js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/moment/moment-timezone/develop/moment-timezone.js)

[contents_from_zones_json](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/moment/moment-timezone/develop/data/packed/latest.json)

It will look a bit like:

```
//! moment.js
;(function (global, factory) {
    typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' ? module.exports = factory() :
    typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(factory) :
    global.moment = factory()
}(this, (function () { 'use strict';
[...]
[...]

//! moment-timezone.js
//! version : 0.5.27
//! Copyright (c) JS Foundation and other contributors
//! license : MIT
//! github.com/moment/moment-timezone
(function (root, factory) {
    "use strict";
[...]
[...]

moment.tz.load({
    "version": "2019c",
    "zones": [
        "Africa/Abidjan|LMT GMT|g.8 0|01|-2ldXH.Q|48e5",
        [...]
        [...]
    ]
});
```